# Permission denied when opening localhost

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, localhost

I had recently installed Apache, PHP and MySQL in Ubuntu. And copied the files I created to the `var/www` directory. But when I open `http://localhost` it is showing

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/index.php' 
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

How can I run my project normally? It was working fine in windows.

Comment: Does /var/www/index.php exist?

Comment: @Steve yes when i create a php file with echo ¨hai¨ it works.

Comment: check your include path. it's different in windows and linux

Comment: Set the permissions on `index.php` to 777 and see if that helps.

Comment: @NicholasPickering changed to 777 now its working...write it as answer i will accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this article, you need to give read/execute permissions to Owner, Group, and Everyone.

Set permissions on the problem file to 777. Note, you should avoid doing this on a server that's accessible from the internet.

http://webomania.wordpress.com/2007/03/12/permission-denied-in-unknown-on-line-0/

Comment: Thanks, 775 permission is suitable in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this problem, look at the line in your ErrorLog, to find out which folder it is trying to access. 
If a  block already exists for that folder, make sure it is set to allow access as necessary. If not, add a  block to your Apache configuration file, allowing access as required. See the example below for folder /usr/local/awstats/htdocs.

Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

for a complete reference, check the [apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration?highlight=%28Client%29%7C%28denied%29%7C%28by%29%7C%28server%29%7C%28configuration%29)