# Getting Error Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, css, dynamic, stream, required

I am new to php but have done a lot of development in other languages. I have inherited a system created by another developer. The code should display a standardized form that is formatted with CSS. It should display a navigation menu on the right with a masthead containing text which changes dynamically, then shows a page and then some content. It works fine running locally on a Mac. I've migrated the project to a PC. When I try to run it's index.php page I get the following errors:

( ! ) Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/styleguide/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear') in Unknown on line 0

After looking through similar errors in the forum I have checked the file permissions and all of the files give me full access and are not read only. I tested Pear, it appears to work fine. Phpinfo shows I have the correct include_path. Other php code I've written runs fine on the PC and can do require_once. The error log shows this same message so I can't determine which files are causing a problem.

I'm running Wampserver 2.5 with Apache v2.4.9 and php v5.5.12 with PEAR Release version 1.9.5 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Here are the contents of Index.php**

```
<?require_once('includes/header.html');
head("Style Guide | Welcome!");
?>
<body id="welcome">
<div class="scroller"></div>
<div class="midcontent">
<?php include("includes/welcome-msthd.html"); ?>
<?php include("includes/welcome-content.html"); ?>
</div>
<div class="holderbox">
<?php include("includes/navs.html"); ?>
</div>
</body>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</HEAD>
</html>
```

**Here are the contents of includes/header.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.allmysons.com/images/amsfav.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="css/css3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Waiting+for+the+Sunrise' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<META NAME="GOOGLEBOT" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE"> 

<!--Bookmark Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function bookmarksite(title,url){
if (window.sidebar) // firefox
window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");
else if(window.opera && window.print){ // opera
var elem = document.createElement('a');
elem.setAttribute('href',url);
elem.setAttribute('title',title);
elem.setAttribute('rel','sidebar');
elem.click();
} 
else if(document.all)// ie
window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);
}
</script>

<!--Remember to add new IDs for new pages below! -->
<style type="text/css">
#welcome li#welcomelink a,
#generalrulesoverview li#generalrulesoverviewlink a,
#employeeuniform li#employeeuniformlink a,
#generalrulessocialmedia li#generalrulessocialmedialink a,
#logodownloads li#logodownloadslink a,
#logodosanddonts li#logodosanddontslink a,
#logocolors li#logocolorslink a,
#logousageandfonts li#logousageandfontslink a,
#emailtemplate li#emailtemplatelink a,
#emailsignatures li#emailsignatureslink a,
#businesscardoverview li#businesscardoverviewlink a,
#orderabusinesscard li#orderabusinesscardlink a,
#brochureordoorhangeroverview li#brochureordoorhangeroverviewlink a,
#thankyoucards li#thankyoucardslink a,
#orderabrochureordoorhanger li#orderabrochureordoorhangerlink a,
#billboards li#billboardslink a,
#changeofaddressform li#changeofaddressformlink a,
#tshirts2 li#tshirtslink a,
#managershirts li#managershirtslink a,
#otherapparel li#otherapparellink a,
#orderapparel li#orderapparellink a,
#taglines li#taglineslink a,
#truckart li#truckartlink a,
#content-submission li#content-submission-link a,
#orderestimatorfolder li#orderestimatorfolderlink a
{ color: #fff; }
a:link {color: #ccc; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;color: #ccc;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;color: #fff;}
a:active {text-decoration: none;color: #ccc;}
</style>

<!--Code below dynamically inserts page title (from page) -->
<?php
function head($title){
if(!$title){
$title="Default page title";
}
?>
<title><?php print $title; ?></title>
</head>
<?php } ?>
```

**Here are the contents of includes/welcome-msthd.html**

```
!--Masthead -->
<div class="versiondate">Version 2.0 | 4-20-12</div>
<div class="header">My Company Name</div>
<div class="header2">Company Style Guide and Resources</div>
<div class="header3">Welcome!</div>
<!--Masthead -->
<div class="versiondate">Version 2.0 | <?php include("includes/updated.html"); ?></div>
<div class="header">All My Sons Moving & Storage</div>
<div class="header2">Company Style Guide and Resources</div>
<div class="header3">Order Estimator Folders</div>
```

**Here are the contents of includes/welcome-content.html**

```
<!--Content -->
<div class="content">
<strong>Some content welcoming the user </strong><br /><br />This is some welcome text <a style="color:#3a7124; text-decoration:underline;" href="mailto:myemail@mycompany.com?subject=Style Guide Help Request">contact us</a> for help.
<div>
<?php include("includes/footer.html"); ?>
</div>
</div>
<!--Content -->
```

Comment: `<?require_once` <= hint. Plus make sure you instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. Otherwise, rename it to `.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: irrelevant. `require` will load any type of file you want, and execute any `<?php ... ?>` code blocks within it. That means you could take a raw binary file, embed a code block within it, and that code block would be executed. doesn't matter if it's .html, .php, .zip, .jpg, whatever. PHP itself doesn't care. That's why I always say there's "no such thing as a php script, only files with php code blocks within them".

Comment: @mark: did you double-paste the index file? the two code blocks are identical. If not, then your header file will be including itself, causing an infinitely recursive inclusion.

Comment: if short tags were off, then you wouldn't get any php errors - nothing'd be executing, after all. you'd just get the raw php code.

Comment: Well I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15596084/ whether it's the same issue as you have, is worth looking into and the link that's in there. Plus, if you made any changes to system files and didn't restart services, that could be an issue.

Comment: My error I did double paste the index file, here is includes/header.html